# Does IE 8 not support push?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I am trying to insert an key/value pair into a serializeArray(from jquery).

So I have something like

```
var form = $('#form');
var sendFormData = form.serializeArray();
sendFormData.push({ "name": "Name", "value": "test"});
```

In firefox this works yet in IE 8 I get

> Line: 51 Error: Object doesn't support
>   this property or method

So it seems to be pointing to this line. So does ie 8 not support push if so what is a way I can add a key/value pair that will work in all browsers(the 5 mains ones firefox, ie8, chrome, opera, safari)

Comment: You accepted an answer but didn't explain why your code was breaking... I'm curious!

Comment: I had a similar problem in IE8 that turned out to be a misleading error message and stack trace.  You have to trace all the way into IE8 code, or it can do some irritating things...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you have works (even in IE8), you can test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZAxzQ/

There must be something outside the question that you're doing to get that error :)

[`.push()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp) has been around as long as the [Array](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_array.asp) object, I've never seen a browser that *doesn't* support it...your unsupported error *has* to be coming from something else.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an exhaustive answer as it won't solve your problem, but the [`Array.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Array/push) method works in IE8:

```
var arr = [];
arr.push({ "name": "Test Name", "value": "Test Value"});
alert(arr[0].name);    // Displays "Test Name"
```

The above can also be re-written as follows:

```
var arr = [];
arr[arr.length] = { "name": "Test Name", "value": "Test Value"};
alert(arr[0].name);    // Displays "Test Name"
```

Comment: The second way is a very weird way to write that IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't got access to IE atm, but I'm sure it does support push. Check that sendFormData is considered an array:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(sendFormData) === '[object Array]';
```

Something else IE likes to do, is tell you there is an error on the line after the error occurred, so it may be part of the form.serializeArray() line.

Comment: Hmm it comes back as false. Not sure why though. Like I mean the code you see is what I have in my js file. I commented everything else just to make sure too.

Comment: What does just the first part come back as? ie Object.prototype.toString.call(sendFormData)
As it's getting generated via a function I'm not sure if it will show function using that method

Answer (score 1):

I thought I had the same problem; but ended up finding that my problem was that IE7-IE8 didn't implement Array.prototype.indexOf. If you want to use that, though, you can go to this link: [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

Answer (score 0):

Of course, <strike>the easiest</strike> another solution is to do something like this:

```
var sendFormData = $("#form").append("<input id='someuniqueID' type='hidden' name='name' value='test' />").serializeArray();
$("#someuniqueID").remove(); //optional could keep it in there if you wanted
```

Comment: I think we'll have to disagree on what the "easiest" way is here...this is more code, less intuitive, and a *lot* more expensive....I really recommend against this, as the other answers show this *shouldn't* be the problem area anyway, this is a simple array/object operation.

Comment: Okay, maybe not the easiest, but it would still solve the problem. I agree it shouldn't be needed, what he has should work, but if for whatever reason he can't debug it, there is also this option. I don't see how it's less intuitive though, looking at it I can see exactly what's going on. But yes, the overhead will be larger for it.